# PHP Calculating the Size (bytes) of current request

Tags: php, mobile, bandwidth

Have a question about monitoring data transfer.

Our situation would be something similar to

```
Apache Server  <-----> Mobile Device
```

We need to do 2 things

1. Calculate the size of the page/raw data getting sent to the mobile
   device.
2. Calculate the size of the request/raw data coming from the
   device.

So in our database we'd be able to store like

```
Device ID | Uploaded | Downloaded
```

The logic for the saving etc is fine, we just need to know how we'd calculate the size of the requests.

I believe when the device sends the server information, we can use PHP to read `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];` to see how big that piece of data is. However not sure how we'd do this the other way around.

Comment: do you mean the http request? or do you mean the request of the initial page as it is loading?

Comment: You could probably use output buffering to calculate the script output size. Not sure what you could do about the response headers though

Comment: Btw., the data your server responds with might not actually be what the mobile device actually _receives_ … since many ISPs apply additional compression and data reduction when they send data over mobile connections …

Comment: @LiamSorsby Sorry not entirely clear what you mean by "the initial page"

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the information, will keep that in mind! The idea of monitoring is just to make sure the device doesn't go over its data-allowance. So if its compressed than that's only a good thing.

Comment: @JohnV. thanks for the tip of output buffering, will give that a look!

Answer (score 0):

It depends how the data is encoded when it's outputed.
If you are using the json_format you can use strlen function.

Example

echo $data; where $data = json_encode(array('what' => 'you, 'send'));

and a simple

$len = strlen($data); will show you.

If it's the right way I understood the question.

Comment: How would you then potentially collect the size of the http header information as well?